# How to do page load in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this menu in HTML / CSS:

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
        <div id="inner"><a href="kingkong.html">King Kong</a></div>
        <div id="inner"><a href="table.html">Table</a></div>
```

CSS:

```
#inner {
    background-color: #547980;
    width: 130px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
#inner:first-child {
    background-color: #547980;
    width: 130px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}            
div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

and I want load page in jQuery.

1. It can be like printer, after click on link from menu it should start from `margin-left` position `140` and printing to `margin-right` position `20` or
2. Loading like book when you go to another page.

But I don't know how to do it. Any advice please?

Comment: Menu should be done preferably using by `ul` and `li`. I think it is much better and more operational.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm a bit confused as well, is the question on how you load a page with javascript, or how to get your menu to be margined? If you only want the menu to look properly, do as @Mardzis  said and use a `<ul>` and `<li>`.

Comment: Is about loading page with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery you can use this script:

```js
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $('.result').load(href);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="kingkong.html">Menu Link</a>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: But I haven't still no idea, what you mean with "like a printer/loading like a book"? Do you mean an animation effect? Maybe such effects? http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/3DHoverEffects/index2.html 
If so, it would be good, when you create another question for this, after some trying by yourself!

Comment: Yes is about animation effect, but your answer is for now good enough. I will try to create that effect and maybe later ask another question as you advise.